# cookie tutorial problem

Tags: java, web-applications, cookies, twebbrowser

http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html

According to this link I was trying to create cookie and send cookie to enter in a cookie site. But it is not working. Is there is any problem in that. I have some confusion on the method `setRequestProperty` of `URLConnection`. I don't understand what are they trying to send by passing `"Cookie"`? Is it only a string or name or value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", myCookie);
> ```

`"Cookie"` in this case is a way to tell the `setRequestProperty` method that the argument (which is really just a `String`) should be treated as a cookie.

[`setRequestProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) may be more useful for many kinds of properties, but [`addRequestProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) would be more useful for cookies, because you can have multiple cookies per request. The properties are specified in [RFC 2068](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt) -- read especially section 14.

Comment: To expand: when a browser connects to a web server, it sends some information like the user agent (what type of browser it is), the page it wants to retrieve, and the cookies it has stored. This information is called `HTTP headers`. A header of "Cookie: a=b" tells the web server that you have a cookie named `a` with a value of `b`. Setting a request property as shown in this answer is how you set headers.